# How to "stack" buttons when deleting one of them in a row? Python, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I have buttons which are generated. Those buttons make a row which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yKXq.png).
When I would delete one of them it would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA0F3.png). What I want to do is "stack" them, maybe somehow delete the ones who were after deleted button, and paste them higher? So it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZGHr.png)
Code:

```py
todoLabel = Label(root, text=todo_new_Entry.get(), image=taskLabel, 
                  compound="center", borderwidth=0)         
todoLabel.place(x=62, y=todoTasks)
todoButton = Button(root, image=taskButton, borderwidth=0, command=disable)
todoButton.place(x=238, y=todoTasks-1)
```

And they are generated whenever some other button is clicked, I guess it doesn't matter

Comment: If you want your widgets to automatically adjust to layout changes, you should be using the `.pack()` or `.grid()` geometry manager, rather than `.place()`.

Comment: Where or how to do you delete it?

Comment: there is a button (this small trash icon on screens in my post)                                                                                               trashB = Button(root, image=trashBI, borderwidth=0, command=delete)                which just does that:                                                                                     def delete():
   global habitTasks
   habitB.destroy()
   habitL.destroy()
   trashB.destroy()
   editB.destroy()
   deadlineB.destroy(). Honestly, I have no idea how does it delete exact buttons and labels that I want to but...it works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting your buttons in a list. Try programmatically rendering them instead of using absolute (x, y) positions. Then when a button is deleted you could remove it from your list of buttons and simply re-render the buttons again.

Comment: But if I want to place buttons in an exact place on the screen, is it possible to do it with just row=, column=?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use something other than `place`. Since you're stacking them, `pack` is the natural choice. Here's a really simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Item(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, text=None):
        super().__init__(master, borderwidth=0, relief="solid")
        label = tk.Label(self, borderwidth=1, relief="solid", text=text, width=20, height=2)
        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=1, relief="solid", width=64, height=64)

        label.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True, padx=2)
        buttonframe.pack(side="right", fill="y", padx=2)

        delete_button = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="X", command=self.destroy)
        delete_button.pack(expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg="bisque")
for item_text in ("one", "two", "three", "four"):
    item = Item(root, text=item_text)
    item.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=2, pady=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is a screenshot after clicking on the "x" next to the item with the label "three":

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great! Also if someone has a problem with placing those labels/buttons in an exact place - I made a Canvas and placed those widgets inside this canvas